# LaTeX and Anki issues - Error executing latex

Tags: mactex, anki

I installed MacTex (the full 4.4gb package) as well as dvipng and received the following error when I opened one of the flash cards downloaded from a GitHub. I also followed that GitHub instructions which are listed here:

[Machine Learning Flash Cards](https://github.com/jessicayung/machine-learning-flashcards)

```
    Error executing latex.
Generated file: /var/folders/lg/_7xvtj1946bdvf38125067h40000gn/T/anki_temp/tmp.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./tmp.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-03-06>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/mathrsfs.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/dvips.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def)
(./tmp.aux)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: dvips

! LaTeX Error: Command \CI already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.10 ...scalebox{1.07}{$\perp\mkern-10mu\perp$}}}}
                                                  

! LaTeX Error: Command \nCI already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.12 \newcommand{\nCI}{\centernot{\CI}}
                                       
[1] (./tmp.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on tmp.dvi (1 page, 332 bytes).
Transcript written on tmp.log.
```

[image: Here is a screenshot of one of the cards with the codes and the errors.]

Comment: did you solve the problem by now? I get same issues on my Anki :-(

Comment: @Hanswurst nope... I gave up and just used a different set of ML cards :(